# jQuery loop get data

Tags: jquery

I made a array and as I go trough that array with an 'for' loop to check for an true input, if the input given is indeed within the array. I got it to work to the point as it ***finds the true value and alerts true***, however ***it alerts false for every other entry*** within the array.

```
$(function(){


 $('button').on('click', function() {
  var name = $('#name').val()


  // Users
  var pers = ['John', 'Apples', 'Emily', 'Banana', 'Chris', 'Orange'];


 for (var i in pers) {
     if( pers[i] == name) {
         $('body').append('<h3> You like ' + pers[++i] + '!');
     } else {
        alert('false');
     } // IF
    } // Loop  
  }); // Button
}); // Function
```

Comment: Well, yes.  It would do exactly that.  Can you just remove that `else` block entirely?

Comment: Cool, so, you have code that does what you say it does..

Comment: as an aside - you shouldn't really use a `for..in` loop to iterate through an array. use `array.forEach` or `for..of` or `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)`

Comment: The for in loop is the only one I currently know, so at this state I'm sure you are right but it is jibrish to me. @Punit

Answer (score 0):

Every beginner seems to get this wrong. You can't know that the element is not found until you finish the loop. You're alerting `false` for every non-matching item, even if there's a match earlier or later. You need to set a flag when you find a match, then at the end of the loop check whether the flag is set or not.

You shouldn't be using an array for this, you should use an object to implement a mapping.

```
var pers = { John: 'Apples', Emily: 'Banana', Chris: 'Orange' };
if (pers.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    $('body').append('<h3> You like ' + pers[name] + '!');
} else {
    alert("false");
}
```

Comment: Well it works, no clue how it works but it does. However the append now spits out the name and not the fruit as the fruit was ++name and without the i loop I honestly dosn't know how to fix that.

Comment: I didn't realize that's what it was doing. You shouldn't use an array, you should use an object that maps names to fruits. `{John: 'Apples', Emily: 'Banana', Chris: 'Orange' }`